# Flutter : Listview horizontal dynamic height

Tags: flutter, dart

i have horizontal listivew inside vertical listview

```
ListView(
 children: [
          Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3.3, ///how can i make this dynamic
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: newlyProduct.length,
            itemBuilder: (context , index) => 
          ),
        ),
 ]
)
```

it's work fine when i run app in phone but when i run it in **IPad** i got `overflow`.

How can i make it with dynamic height to run app in any screen size

Comment: what is `phoneSize` here? Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: sorry its ```MediaQuery.of(context).size```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by dynamic, beacause it's already dynamic based on your code: the `height` of your horizontal `ListView` is based on the height of the device screen, making it dynamic.

If you want to avoid overflow issues on the `Y` axis, you need to make sure that any children of your `ListView` has not a set `height` higher than its parent.

You can also use flex, by wrapping your `ListView` into a `column`, and using `expanded`:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3.3,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              controller: _scrollController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: newlyProduct.length,
              itemBuilder: (context , index) => 
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
 ]
)
```